# ActionMailer view link not clickable

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, actionmailer, clickable

I've tried inserting a link into my email view using the normal way of an anchor tag and while the text appears to look like a link in the email sent (blue text color), it isn't clickable. How can I can the anchor tag work? Since ActionMailer uses erb files as the view, all I have added is
`<%= link_to "My site name", 'my_site_URL' %>` but the link isn't clickable in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my href attribute